# how to achieve normalization in solr fields? Experts please advice

Tags: java, mysql, sql, solr, normalization

I am having data in a table that I want to index to Apache solr server.

### Sample data :

India | Executive / Sr. Executive | 01/01/2015  | Position Executive / Sr. Executive

In my xls **India and 01/01/2015** may come multiple times and If I index them(dupliucates) then that wont be a good idea to index same value again and again.

Any suggestion , how to achieve normalization in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign

Comment: Thanks Mauricio ,but this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link a database to solr and then you can easily normalise the data .
For deleting/retrieving a row use solr delete/get option as per wiki postd by Mauricio Scheffer .